# unable to execute shell script

Tags: java, linux

```
#!/bin/bash
#echo off
echo -n Enter acl File Location
read acl
echo -n Enter target sql File Location
read sql
cd bin
pwd
java -cp .:../lib/dom4j-1.6.1.jar:../lib/poi-3.8-20120326.jar:../lib/poi-ooxml-3.8-20120326.jar:../lib/poi-ooxml-schemas-3.8-20120326.jar:../lib/stax-api-1.0.1.jar:
.:../lib/xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar com/paywithisis/gateway/utility/XLSXToSQLConverter $acl $sql
cd ..
echo $acl
echo $sql
```

THE ERROR MSG:

```
../lib/xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar: line 1: PK: command not found
../lib/xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar: line 2: Lk¶6: command not found
../lib/xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar: line 3:Kk¶6KAKÛnMETA-INF/MANIFEST.MF}AkÂ@…ï
                                                                           ûæØv“h!7-„Úƒ¶â­¬ÉXÙÙ°: No such file or directory
../lib/xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar: line 3: ¶úï›5: command not found
../lib/xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar: line 4: B¯óÞ: command not found
../lib/xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar: line 4: óÞ¬
                                      5
                                       ¬¶èCã¨„‰N¥˜ÓŸÉ¼3Õ¡ŸõâLO¥xöhkµ¸¡³ÏI¦öi›Áª©¼
                                                                                    —Àh,©ÒRHñf,–àüWb®¼älÛ=: command not found
../lib/xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar: line 5: IÏsÖñxjgÛE”à{È™Îuªü´HŸòBŠ¥íZŒU½7Ül=°õ}gKýOÜÕÎy6îÀ?Æ#¼¸ÕWËÝÊÇúµ„#sW: command not found
../lib/xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar: line 5: cµ[œØ:þàPK: command not found
../lib/xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar: line 6: 9k¶6org/PK: No such file or directory
../lib/xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar: line 7: 9k¶6
                                       org/apache/PK: No such file or directory
../lib/xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar: line 8: :k¶6org/apache/xmlbeans/PK: No such file or directory
../lib/xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar: line 9: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
../lib/xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar: line 9: 9k¶6«f)¸}¿'org/apache/xmlbeans/BindingConfig.class•T]OA=Ó.jµˆÈ7*‚Ð²úBŒ I%Å`j©mC$>é2-
                                                                                                                              Ë,n·¦?KäÁÄ€?ÊxgwÅÒ.´¼ÌÝ½wÏ¹çž¹íï??~x=ŽRƒèGZK1,Ç°ÃÓV&²ï
        å½ýí|9[ÜÊlf÷³Ëû™b1³Çþ”³šÎO¹q(ôæ‰U\Öõmé
```

Comment: please edit ur post to human readable format

Comment: A bit more effort into the question and you'd probably motivate some people to try and answer it. Otherwise the question might get closed quickly.

Answer (score 4):

The problem appears to be with the following command that got split into two:

```
java -cp .:../lib/dom4j-1.6.1.jar:../lib/poi-3.8-20120326.jar:../lib/poi-ooxml-3.8-20120326.jar:../lib/poi-ooxml-schemas-3.8-20120326.jar:../lib/stax-api-1.0.1.jar:
.:../lib/xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar com/paywithisis/gateway/utility/XLSXToSQLConverter $acl $sql
```

You need to remove the newline before the `.:../lib/xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar`

Otherwise the shell tries to execute `../lib/xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar` directly, resulting in the error you're seeing.

Comment: I have tried this too.removed .:.. and but why it is tryying to execute the file why not others.the code is working fine with .bat in windows..

Answer (score 2):

It look like it's trying to *run* a JAR file as a script. The `PK` and `MANIFEST` strings are those found in the compressed JAR files.

You might want to check that you don't have an errant space (or other funny character) in your class path.

Answer (score 0):

the same issue happened to me when i copied the java command from bat file to sh file.. in windows the classpath separator is ';' while in linux the separator is ':'

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Please don't post "me too" as an answer. Instead, you may star this question as a favorite to be notified of any new answers. Once you have sufficient reputation, [you may also upvote](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up) it or [write a comment](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment) instead..